# Can you tile a heart with dominoes?

Tags: geometry, tiling, polyomino

For a positive integer $n$, let $R_n$ be the set of integer lattice points $(x, y)$ such that

- $0 \leq x < 2n$
- $0 \leq y < 4n$
- $x \leq y$
- $y \leq 5n - x$
- $y \leq x + 3n$,

and let $L_n = \{(-x, y) \mid (x, y) \in R_n\}$. Define the *$n$th heart board* to be $L_n \cup R_n$. The first four heart boards look like this:

[image: heart boards]

**Can heart boards ever be tiled with dominoes?**

The $n$th heart board seems to have size $10n^2 + 3n - 3$. This is even iff $n$ is odd, so only the odd heart boards have any hope to be tiled. With a computer search I've verified that no heart board with $n \leq 20$ can be tiled using dominoes. I don't see how to extend any "forcing" argument to arbitrary integers, but I suspect that there is some nice pattern. (Any possible tiling seems to only use "upright" dominoes, for example.)

Comment: I presume you're familiar with arguments like a chessboard with opposite corners deleted being non-tileable due to having different numbers of black and white squares, with each domino covering exactly one of each color -- have you checked to see whether these heart boards are nontileable for that reason?

Comment: @GregoryJ.Puleo That's a great suggestion! Using the coloring $(-1)^{x + y}$, it looks like odd heart boards have a "color difference" of exactly 2. I will have to think about proving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No heart boards can be tiled with dominoes.**

Gregory Puleo's suggestion turns into an excellent proof.

"Color" the heart with $+1$ and $-1$ so that the spaces alternate signs. Every domino then covers exactly one $+1$ and one $-1$, so the heart board will not be tileable if there are more $+1$'s than $-1$'s, or vice versa. It suffices to consider the heart a single column at a time.

Fix some $x \in \{0, 1, 2, \dots, 2n - 1\}$. What is the height of the $x$th column? Using the given constraints, it is exactly

$$\min(5n - x, x + 3n, 4n) - x + \delta,$$

where $\delta = 0$ if the minimum is $4n$, and $1$ otherwise. In the first case for the minimum, we get

$$5n - x - x + 1 = 5n - 2x + 1.$$

This is even if $n$ is odd, so the "color difference" is $0$. In the second case for the minimum, we get

$$x + 3n - x + 1 = 3n + 1,$$

which is even if $n$ is odd, so the color difference is again $0$. In the third case we get

$$4n - x,$$

but the conditions $4n \leq 5n - x$ and $4n \leq x + 3n$ happen to imply $x = n$, so the color difference is actually $3n$, and this occurs in only one column. This is *odd* if $n$ is odd, so there is exactly one more plus sign than minus sign in this column (or the other way around).

This all means that the odd heart boards have a color difference of exactly two, one from column $x = n$, and one from column $x = -n$, so they cannot be tiled by dominoes. The even heart boards have an odd number of spaces, so they obviously cannot be tiled with dominoes.